# plotly: the custom hover text feature is broken

Tags: plotly, r-plotly, plotly.js

It seems that custom `plotly` hovers are broken. I am using a custom hover text and `hoveron='points+fills'` to show this both on points and on the filled shape. When hovering on points, as expected it shows my custom string. However, when hovering on the shape, it shows a different hover (without my custom string)!

Example code:

```
library(plotly)
data.frame(AA=c(2,3,3,2,NA, 6,7,7,6,NA),
       BB=c(2,2,3,2,NA, 6,6,7,6,NA),
       CC=c(rep('abc', 5), rep('xyz', 5)),
       LL=c(rep('A', 5), rep('B', 5))) %>%
plot_ly() %>%
         add_trace(x=~AA,
                   y=~BB,
                   text=~paste('<br> <b>Example</b> of <em>custom</em> hover text <br>', LL, '<br>', CC, '<br>.'),
                   split=~LL, 
                   mode="lines", 
                   fill="toself", 
                   hoveron='points+fills',
                   type="scatter", 
                   color = I(c(rep(toRGB("black", 1), 5),
                               rep(toRGB("red", 1), 5)))
                   )
```

Hovering on point (working as expected with the custom hover text):
[image: hover point]

Hovering on the filled shape (not working - the custom hover text is not present):
[image: hover fill]

Another side of this issue can be demonstrated below. Replacing                        `hoveron='points+fills'` by `hoveron='fills'`. The custom text is visible nowhere.

```
library(plotly)
data.frame(AA=c(2,3,3,2,NA, 6,7,7,6,NA),
           BB=c(2,2,3,2,NA, 6,6,7,6,NA),
           CC=c(rep('abc', 5), rep('xyz', 5)),
           LL=c(rep('A', 5), rep('B', 5))) %>%
    plot_ly() %>%
             add_trace(x=~AA,
                       y=~BB,
                       text=~paste('<br> <b>Example</b> of <em>custom</em>     hover text <br>', LL, '<br>', CC, '<br>.'),
                       split=~LL, 
                       mode="lines", 
                       fill="toself", 
                       hoveron='fills',
                       type="scatter", 
                       color = I(c(rep(toRGB("black", 1), 5),
                                   rep(toRGB("red", 1), 5)))
                       )
```

Result:
[image: another example]

This is probably a bug, any idea about how to fix it?

Thanks

output of sessionInfo():

```
R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 17.10

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas/libblas.so.3
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopenblasp-r0.2.20.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=pt_BR.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=pt_BR.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=pt_BR.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=pt_BR.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=pt_BR.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] bindrcpp_0.2  plotly_4.7.1  ggplot2_2.2.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.16        bindr_0.1.1         magrittr_1.5       
 [4] munsell_0.4.3       xtable_1.8-2        viridisLite_0.3.0  
 [7] colorspace_1.3-2    R6_2.2.2            rlang_0.2.0        
[10] httr_1.3.1          plyr_1.8.4          dplyr_0.7.4        
[13] tools_3.4.4         grid_3.4.4          data.table_1.10.4-3
[16] gtable_0.2.0        crosstalk_1.0.0     htmltools_0.3.6    
[19] yaml_2.1.18         lazyeval_0.2.1      assertthat_0.2.0   
[22] digest_0.6.15       tibble_1.4.2        shiny_1.0.5        
[25] purrr_0.2.4         tidyr_0.8.0         htmlwidgets_1.0    
[28] mime_0.5            glue_1.2.0          compiler_3.4.4     
[31] pillar_1.2.1        scales_0.5.0        jsonlite_1.5       
[34] httpuv_1.3.6.2      pkgconfig_2.0.1
```

Comment: can you add the output of `sessionInfo()`?

Comment: Sure, I've just added.

Comment: What text are you expecting to see? The hovertext shows information which is specific to a point, so showing the same information for the shape would be confusing.

Comment: This is a demonstration of the issue, so the data makes no sense. What I want to say is that the custom text hover is not working as expected, since it does not consider `text` information. Note, in a real case, one may want to put something useful in the custom hover.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `name` attribute seems to work (R 3.6.1, plotly package v.4.9.0) - as opposed to `text` which just associates a blob of text with each row/point, `name` serves as a grouping variable in this context:

```
library(plotly)

geod = data.frame(
  cx = c(0,10,6,0,5,5,9,5),
  cy = c(1,8,2,1,6,8,7,6),
  grps = rep(c('foobar','barfou'),each = 4),
  ptxt = LETTERS[1:8]
)
plot_ly() %>% 
  add_polygons(
    data = geod,
    x = ~cx, y = ~cy,
    name = ~grps, text = ~ptxt,
    hoveron = 'points+fills'
  )
```

Another nice thing about this behavior is that we don't need to insert `NA` values to delimit groups.

If you want to customize the hover labels quite differently for fills vs. points then it may be more straightforward to just separate into two separate traces: here, hovering over points shows *both* the group name and the x/y/text, which I don't always find desirable.

[image: hover over point]

[image]